# Populate JSTree with JSON from JSP

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jsp, jstree

I am trying to populate a JSTree with a JSON String which i retrieve from a JSP file.

This is my attempt:

```
function initDirs() {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    req.open("GET", "svntojson.jsp?expandedNodePath=/root", true); 
    req.onreadystatechange = function receive() {
        if (req.readyState == 4) {
            createTree(req.responseText.trim());
        }
    };
    req.send();
}    

initDirs();

function createTree(jsonData) {
    console.log(jsonData);
    $('#treeview').jstree({
        'core' : {
            'data' : jsonData
        }
    });
}
```

Unfortunately the jstree is empty. I logged the returned json which looks good to me:

```
 { "id" : "root", "parent" : "#", "text" : "root" },
 {"id":"branches","parent":"root","text":"branches"},
 {"id":"README.txt","parent":"root","text":"README.txt"},
 {"id":"svn.ico","parent":"root","text":"svn.ico"},
 {"id":"Desktop.ini","parent":"root","text":"Desktop.ini"},
 {"id":"vgt","parent":"root","text":"vgt"},
 {"id":"trunk","parent":"root","text":"trunk"},
 {"id":"format","parent":"root","text":"format"}
```

If is set the returned json manually it works:

```
function createTree(jsonData) {
    console.log(jsonData);
    $('#treeview').jstree({
        'core' : {

            'data' : [
                 { "id" : "root", "parent" : "#", "text" : "root" },
                 {"id":"branches","parent":"root","text":"branches"},
                 {"id":"README.txt","parent":"root","text":"README.txt"},
                 {"id":"svn.ico","parent":"root","text":"svn.ico"},
                 {"id":"Desktop.ini","parent":"root","text":"Desktop.ini"},
                 {"id":"vgt","parent":"root","text":"vgt"},
                 {"id":"trunk","parent":"root","text":"trunk"},
                 {"id":"format","parent":"root","text":"format"} 
            ]
        }
    });
}
```

Anyone who can help me to show my returned json in the treeview ?

**EDIT:**
This is my final solution:

```
    function initDirs() {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var path = "root/";
    req.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    req.open("GET", "svntojson.jsp?expandedNodePath="+path, true); 
    req.onreadystatechange = function receive() {
        if (req.readyState == 4) {
           var jsonData = JSON.parse(req.responseText.trim());
           $('#treeview').jstree(true).settings.core.data = jsonData;
           $('#treeview').jstree(true).refresh();
        }

    };

    req.send();
}    


initDirs();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`req.responseText.trim()` return a string, so you need to convert this JSON into a Javascript object.

Try the following :

```
if (req.readyState == 4) {
    var respData = JSON.parse(req.responseText.trim());
    createTree(respData);
}
```

Comment: Thanks I won't have the time to test it today. I will have a look at this solution tommorow and come back to you, if it fails.

Comment: Thanks i updated my question, your answer helped me a lot. I am not sure how i could possibly miss to convert the string to a JSON Object.